# How to auto-generate filename of PDF in wkhtmltopdf based on the page title?

Tags: command-line, pdf, download, command-line-arguments, html-files

I'm using the following syntax to generate PDF from URL:

```
wkhtmltopdf http://example.com/ example.pdf
```

Is there any way to generate filename automatically based on its page title?

So I'm expecting to not hardcode the filename as above.

List of option is extensive (`-H`) and maybe I've missed something, but the only one which I think could work is `--read-args-from-stdin`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the following workaround:

```
wkhtmltopdf http://example.com "$(curl -s http://example.com | grep -o "<title>[^<]*" | tail -c+8).pdf"
```

Which will generate file named: *Example Domain.pdf*.

The only downside is that the connection needs to be performed twice as well as you've to type URL twice, but in the script it can be a variable. And the filename it-self isn't printed to the output.